# Proper *pattern* for implementing graph algorithms?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have an `AdjacencyList` class and I want all graph **algorithms** to be seperated from it. Let's say all algorithms are **functors** and derive from `GraphAlgorithm` abstract base class. How do I make it work?

I am currently thinking,

```
class AdjacencyList
{
    // ...
    friend class GraphAlgorithm;
    // ...
};
```

But is it allowing **GraphAlgorithm's sub-classes** to access private members of **AdjacencyList**?

Any other approaches are welcome.

Comment: @Yavar I have to eventually implement `all pair shortest path` algorithm for extra large graphs (using STXXL library). This is my project. I have checked BGL but I don't think it's suitable for `external memory graphs`.

Comment: Thats good! What do you mean when you say external memory graphs, are you talking about persistence here?

Comment: O Ok maybe you are talking about memory mapped stuff :) Got it Good Question +1.

Comment: @Yavar `external memory graphs` = graphs so huge that they do not fit in primary memory. In my case, they reside in hard drive. The trick in this type of algorithms is to reduce the I/O (instead of execution time of instructions) occurring between primary and secondary memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But is it allowing GraphAlgorithm's sub-classes to access private members of AdjacencyList?

No, it does not. Friendship is not transitive.

Regardless, whenever you need a `friend` declaration, you should regard it as a code smell and re-think your design.

I would rather have getters in the `AdjacencyList` and so a `GraphAlgorithm` can operate on the members it has access to from the methods of `AdjacencyList`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at the Strategy pattern: "Define a family of algorithms, encapsulate each one, and make them interchangeable. Strategy lets the algorithm vary independently from clients that use it."

For examples visit[Strategy Pattern on dofactory](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx)
[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern)

Comment: I will not be implementing a `family of algorithms`.